# Can I use the bootstrap grid with the grid classes inside my Angular components?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I want something like

```
<my-row>
  <my-col>Content</my-col>
  <my-col>Content</my-col>
</my-row>
```

Where the divs with the bootstrap classes are inside my components. I know this worked with Bootstrap 3 but the latest bootstrap use Flexbox and inline styled components around the cols seems to break the styles.

```
<div class="row">
  <span>
    <div class="col-md-6">Content</div>
  </span>
  <span>
    <div class="col-md-6">Content</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

The span in this example also breaks the layout. Is there a way to have my component structure work as a grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a HostBinding.

```
@HotstBinding('class')
classes: string;

@Input()
set gridClasses(classes: string) {
  this.classes = classes;
}
```

and I can use the input to set the classes on the component selector now.